# Android center aligns images

Tags: android, html, css, html-email

I have very simple html. It's an email header. My problem is, it displays perfectly on iOS but Android center aligns the logo and the button when I run an actual email test. Browsers displays it well. It's just email clients where it changes. The logo is suppose to be left aligned and the orange button right aligned.

[image: Android Screenshot]

[image: iPhone Screenshot]

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse:collapse!important">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="30%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
      <a href="%%text01%%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#b5b5b5;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none">
        <img class="logo" src="http://image.info.olx.co.za/lib/fe9413727563037e74/m/1/121115_logo.png" alt="OLX" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border:0;height:auto;line-height:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td class="cta-sell-orange" align="right" valign="center" width="70%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
      <a align="right" style="margin-right: 7px;font-size: 13px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #ffffff;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;background-color: #ff7800 !important;-moz-border-radius: 3px !important;-webkit-border-radius: 3px !important;border-radius: 2px !important;border: 1px solid #ff6000 !important;display: inline-block !important;cursor: pointer !important;padding: 10px 25px !important; margin: 3px !important; font-weight: bold !important;"
      href="%%text02%%">Sell your item</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ericpayi/ksgvf7st/

Comment: Isn't `align` deprecated?

Comment: this is for HTML email, not web.  Align is a necessity in email still.

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of what it looks like on Android and what it is supposed to look like (maybe the iOS rendering?)

Comment: @Gortonington I've attached the Android screenshot. Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to attach both because I don't have much reputation. The OLX logo needs to be left aligned and the orange button right aligned. At the moment, they are both centered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears if you define your two TDs in PX instead of percentage it works fine. I know there is an issue with Table width 100% in Android 5.1, but was unaware of this as an issue before.

See below Screenshot from the pixel defined code:

[image: Android5.1 Test Image]

See below for the updated code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse:collapse!important">
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left" width="170" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
<a href="%%text01%%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#b5b5b5;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none">
<img class="logo" src="http://image.info.olx.co.za/lib/fe9413727563037e74/m/1/121115_logo.png" alt="OLX" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border:0;height:auto;line-height:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;">
</a>
</td>
<td class="cta-sell-orange" align="right" valign="center" width="430" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0">
<a align="right" style="margin-right: 7px;font-size: 13px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #ffffff;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none;background-color: #ff7800 !important;-moz-border-radius: 3px !important;-webkit-border-radius: 3px !important;border-radius: 2px !important;border: 1px solid #ff6000 !important;display: inline-block !important;cursor: pointer !important;padding: 10px 25px !important; margin: 3px !important; font-weight: bold !important;" href="%%text02%%">Sell your item</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped!